# How to make WordPress views counter count 1 view by 10 views

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have this code for WordPress views counter

```
<?php
// function to display number of posts.
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

It counts                   1 viewer = 1 view
I want to make it counts    1 viewer = 10 view

How can I make this ?

Comment: how do you call your functions?

Comment: I used this code from this page / https://wp-snippets.com/post-views-without-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Change `$count++;` to `$count = $count + 10;`

Wouldn't this inflate your page counts?

Comment: I have tried this but it still count with 1 view.
What is the mean of inflate page counts ?

Comment: You'd be reporting more views then actually happened; ten times as many views.

It's possible that the function `update_post_meta` might contain some coding to prevent the view count from incrementing from anything other than 1. Have you tried hardcoding a value in the update statement and setting if that works?